# Image moving upwards

Tags: html, css, image, hover

I have a problem with hover effect. When I hover my image, everything works, but your cursor has to EXACTLY ON the image troughout the animation. So i need to extend the hover area from start of the image till the end of animation image. So everypart of the animation would be covered.

Sorry, I dont have a web space. So if you trust me, you can download the .rar file from dropbox. I promise I didnt plant any viruses there :). Just launch the Meist.html, its the "index" of the page. Try to hover over the Coffee cup above the footer.

Any questions just throw them away, cause my native language is not english.

Comment: Here is the link
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1szq77mvz2s32rz/Fava.rar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put padding around the image

```
img {
    padding: 30px
}
```

This will extend the area by 30px all around your image. Be sure to use padding and not margin as margin will not make the space created clickable.

Comment: Anyway to make it transparent or insvisible ?

Comment: it will show the background color of the current div. If that has no background color set then it will show the background color of what ever it is nested within.

Answer (score 0):

Put the image in a div, the use a selector like:

```
#your_div:hover img { 
    /* Do your stuff */
}
```